# Class distribution error

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is the class:

```
class Player:
    #variables
    hand = []
    name = 'Test Player'
    #functions
    def take(self, card): #allows player to take a card
        self.hand.append(card)
    def __str__(self):
        msg = self.name
        if len(self.hand) > 0:
            msg = msg + "\nIn hand:"
            for card in self.hand:
                msg = msg + ' ' + card.short_name
        return msg
```

here is the function:

```
def deal(players):
    deck = Deck.generate_deck()
    if len(players) <= 4:
        for player in players:
            for cards in range (0, 7):
                card = random.choice(deck)
                player.take(card)
                deck.remove(card)
    else:
        for player in players:
            for cards in range (0, 5):
                card = random.choice(deck)
                player.take(card)
                deck.remove(card)
    return deck
```

Here is the problem. When I call the function to deal cards to five players this is what i get.

```
Player 1
In hand: JC 2H KD 8H QD KH AS 10S QC 10H AH 6S JD 4H 5S 4S 9C 3C QH 9S AD 6D 8S 10C 7C
25

Player 2
In hand: JC 2H KD 8H QD KH AS 10S QC 10H AH 6S JD 4H 5S 4S 9C 3C QH 9S AD 6D 8S 10C 7C
25

Player 3
In hand: JC 2H KD 8H QD KH AS 10S QC 10H AH 6S JD 4H 5S 4S 9C 3C QH 9S AD 6D 8S 10C 7C
25

Player 4
In hand: JC 2H KD 8H QD KH AS 10S QC 10H AH 6S JD 4H 5S 4S 9C 3C QH 9S AD 6D 8S 10C 7C
25

Player 5
In hand: JC 2H KD 8H QD KH AS 10S QC 10H AH 6S JD 4H 5S 4S 9C 3C QH 9S AD 6D 8S 10C 7C
25
```

p.s. The number afterwards was a small debug thing in my testing code and had no affect.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Least Astonishment" in Python: The Mutable Default Argument](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that your `hand = []` list is attached to the class; it is a class attribute and shared between instances.

Create a new list for each player in the `__init__` method:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self):
        self.hand = []
```